# Read Zip file from an URL and download specific .csv file in python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

The following reproducible code is giving me: BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") error. I don't know how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO, BytesIO, TextIOWrapper
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gQGYF8TaznCfdevo7-MsHW5IcwftZWP_/view?usp=sharing'
zip_file_name = 'high_dimensional_datasets.zip'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url +  urllib.request.quote(zip_file_name))

zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))

data = TextIOWrapper(zipfile.open('high42.csv'), encoding='utf-8')

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Comment: Well, have you checked that `url + urllib.request.quote(zip_file_name)` gives you the url to a valid zip file? Write the output of `resp.read()` to a file. Can you open it using a zip program? If not, then the file is not a zip file, and we don't know how to fix it either.

Comment: @PranavHosangadiyes the link leads to a zip file where upon clicking download it is downloaded. It seems however that the URL is wrong. This is the reason I posted it, so you can try it. It is a valid zip file because I have downloaded and extracted it manually.

Comment: The link leads to a zip file _in your browser_. Did you inspect the output of `resp.read()`? It  is most definitely **not** a zip file.

Comment: This is the output:
`resp.read()
Out[19]: b''`

I don't know how to write it to a file, but this output is also the same with a working example.

Comment: You can only read the response _once_. The first time you read it, you get a html file with a whole bunch of javascript. I expect the javascript renders the page and redirects you to download the zip file, but it is not a zip file, which is why you get the error. Have you tried using the API instead of accessing web pages? https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/